# How can I use this session to redirect to a splash page if the user has not already seen it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm attempting to make the site redirect the user to a splash page first, before they see the main `default.aspx` homepage. Likewise, if they have seen the splash page before, it ignores the redirect:

```
if (Session["splashVisited"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("/default-splash.aspx");
    Session["splashVisited"] = true;
}
```

But then when the user clicks: ENTER SITE on the splash page, it redirects again to the splash page.

Have I not set a session to true though?

Sorry, beginner warning :-)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no guarantee that any code is executed after `Response.Redirect`. Either you set the value in your session in the target page (which would be preferred), or you change the order of commands in your `if` body:

```
if (Session["splashVisited"] == null)
{
    Session["splashVisited"] = true;
    Response.Redirect("/default-splash.aspx");
}
```

A word of advice: using the session is usually not the best way to transport information like page visits. You should try to think about other solutions, such as page parameters or cookies.

Comment: Thank youuuuuu!!! Can I control how long until the session expires? Say.... A day?

Comment: You can in your web.config.

Comment: @davvv But note that setting the session timeout to a day means that everything you keep in session stays there for a day *after* the user last visited the site - can your server handle that for *all* visitors? Plus it might be reset when the server restarts. Better use a cookie for this - easier to set a longer timeout and the user stores it, not the server.